# How to use tinymce-equation-editor with React TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am using [tinymce-react](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react). I want to add [tinymce-equation-editor](https://github.com/insoutt/tinymce-equation-editor) as a plugin with it.

My editor currently:

```
<Editor
      value={value}
      init={{
        menubar: true,
        plugins: [
          'code',
          'image,paste advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
        ],
        external_plugins: {
          equation_editor:
            'https://unpkg.com/mathlive@0.79.0/dist/mathlive.min.js',
        },
        toolbar:
          'formatselect | bold italic color backcolor image,paste | convertButton equation_editor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
      bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat',
        setup: handleInit,
      }}
    />
```